# Different IE behavior when calling localhost or hostname

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer

I have a simple html page generated by a servlet on websphere .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Server Management</title>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;URL="console"' />
<script> 
function setVal(command, i){
var elmnt = document.getElementById('myvalue')
elmnt.value = command + '-' + i;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action='console'>
  <button type='submit' onclick='setVal("stop", this.value)' name='stop' value='0'>Stop</button>
  <button type='submit' onclick='setVal("start", this.value)' name='start' value='0'>Start</button>
  <button type='submit' onclick='setVal("status", this.value)' name='status' value='0'>Status</button>
  <div style='display:inline'>Server 3 is <div style='display:inline;color:green'>UP</div> </div>
  <br/>
  <input  type='hidden' name='myvalue' id='myvalue'  value='bla'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The thing is, when I call localhost(or 127.0.0.1) to upload the page everithing works as expected,  and the right values are sent

```
http://localhost:9081/MyApp/MyAction?status=0&myvalue=status-0
```

BUT when I use the hostname (or IP) instead of localhost the element's innerHTML is sent rather then it's value, which of course cause errors.

```
http://myhostname:9081/MyApp/MyAction?status=Status&myvalue=status-Status
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about the IE version... Turning on competability mode fixed the issue.

A better solution is adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

to the HTML.

Thank you Microsoft for the great apps you give us